# downloaded file in primefaces datatable is null

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, download

I want to retrive file from database and display in primefaces datatable.I use this code :

```
        public StreamedContent getInputFileStreamedContent() {

     if (this.document == null){
            this.document = new byte[0];
        }
        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.document);
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream);
    }

}
```

But When I click on command link,it return null.

Xhtml code:

```
<p:column >
                  <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="docId" />
                    </f:facet>   
                    <h:commandLink value="#{o.userId}"  rendered="#{o.inputFileStreamedContent != null}">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{o.inputFileStreamedContent}"></p:fileDownload>
                    </h:commandLink>
                </p:column>
```

Comment: So you are saying this works outside a datable?

Comment: I don t check it outside of datatable

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution and put if someone has my problem.I should add file Content type and file name to DefaultSteamContent.So my new code:

```
    public StreamedContent getInputFileStreamedContent() {

    if (this.document == null) {
        this.document = new byte[0];
    }
    InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.document);
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream,this.fileContentType.toString(), this.fileName);
}
```